# <symbol> component usage in React

Tags: reactjs

I am using `react-digraph` and in the example I've seen the following code:

```
const EmptyShape = (
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 100 100" id="empty">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
  </symbol>
)
```

I can't find where the symbol component comes from... Is this a React thing?
Also, is it possible to insert a FontAwesome icon inside the circle?

Answer (score 0):

See here for some documentation of the SVG symbol element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol

All of the elements the const EmptyShape are svg elements.

I think one option would be to override the 'renderNode' prop, and write a custom renderer...

If you did solve this problem, I'd be very interested, as it's relevant for something I'm looking into.